# Git: importing from bare or from non-bare

Tags: git, repository, git-bare

I have been hosting bare repositories in my Home local server (Mac Mini).

It has been performing really slow (maybe due to lack of git optimization for large files)

So to solve this problem, I'm thinking to move my bare repo to BitBucket private repository. Just to give it a try.

When I tried to import to bitbucket from my bare repository. It has many problems, such as it only imports my staging branch.

and when I do

```
git branch
```

on the git bare repo directory
it only shows my staging in my branch list.
then I do `git fsck --full`.
it shows many errors related to pack.
another problem is that inside the git bare repo directory, I found another folder that has the same name as the repo directory itself. for example: my repo directory name is repo.git/. this continues to repo.git/repo.git/repo.git/repo.git.

From these problems, I think I screwed up my bare repository badly. So I'm thinking to remove this bare repo and do the import to bitbucket from my normal/non-bare repository.

So my question is:
is there any difference even any small difference, to import from bare repository and to import from non-bare repository?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there any difference even any small difference, to import from bare repository and to import from non-bare repository?

No, providing that your bare repo had all your branches.

Pushing from a (non-bare) repo is [explained here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Importing+code+from+an+existing+project):

> If you want, you can push several branches at once to your Bitbucket repository. To do this, do the following:

- List all the branches to make sure you have what you want:
  `git branch -a`
- Make sure the remote `origin` in your local repository points to Bitbucket.
  For example, if you are using ssh with Bitbucket, you would use the following:
  `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/youraccount/reponame.git`
- Then push all the branches to Bitbucket:
  `git push -u origin --all`.